# Octave inputParser.addRequired is undefined

Tags: octave

I have updated my Octave from version 3.8.2 to 4.4.1, now one part of a code doesn't work as before, and I don't even understand what this lines should be good for.

The problem occurs at the beginning of a function witch gets a year and returns 0, 1 weather it's a leap year or not.

```
 22 p = inputParser;
 23 p = p.addRequired('Year',@(x) all(isnumeric(x)));
 24 p = p.parse(Year);
```

The error I get is:

```
error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined
error: called from
    leapyear at line 23 column 3
```

So why there is this `inputParser` at all? And how can I get it to work in the new Octave version?

Unfortunately there is no documentation for the `inputParser` function:

```
octave:23> help(inputParser)
error: help: invalid input
```

Comment: Either type `help inputParser` or `help('inputParser')`. _Not_ `help(inputParser)`. This would just attempt to run the inputParser function without arguments and then return its result to the help function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot guess as to why that code worked in Octave 3.8, the oldest documentation for Octave available online is for version 4.0.

The [Octave 4.4 documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Multiple-Return-Values.html#XREFinputParser) specifies that `inputParser.addRequired()` doesn't have an output value. So change line 23 by removing `p =`, so that it reads:

```
p.addRequired('Year',@(x) all(isnumeric(x)));
```

Note that [MATLAB's documentation for `inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) says the same thing.